# Colaboratory|OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error

Tags: python

**Colaboratory**

There is no error or bug in code and when I run the processing a few times, it will send the error. When I run the epoch, the first epoch never has an error, but the second epoch (or even the third) will have some trouble. I think it makes some mistakes on the path through the colab between my windows.

**OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry, we can't accept images of code or errors. Post those as text, so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: Check [\[SO\]: How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
for more asking related details.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone!I think the trouble makes between among two .ipynb. is the os.I should define the different environments and restart it again when we should run the different code.